# For Loop Behaviour

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This question is regarding Javascript for loops, where I've been having some weird behaviour.

My For loop currently looks like this:

```
var UnitAmount = 2;//(value verified, yet not declared like this)
var DamageAmount = [1,3];//(value verified, yet not declared like this)
function forcerefresh () {
  for( i=0 ; i < UnitAmount ; i++ ) {
  //(10 lines of Stuff)
var check = 0;
    for (c = 0; c < DamageAmount[i] ; c++ ) {
      debug[0] = damage[i][c].getElementsByClassName("writedamage")[0];
      debug[1] = damage[i][c];
      debug[2] = unit[i];
      check = check + 1;
      console.info("Unit:",i,"Loop:",c,"Debug:",debug,"Check:",check, "Race:",unitrace[i], unit[i].dataset.race);
      alert("Debug:"+ debug );
      damageCalc(damage[i][c].getElementsByClassName("writedamage")[0],damage[i][c],unit[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

In here, debug, alert, Check and the console write call are already added to attempt to find the problem - I'm getting an infinite loop here.

The output im getting in the console shows that while the i constant walks as intended, but the c Iteration count starts at 0, jumps to 2, and then stays 2 - and since the DamageAmount[1] = 3, this creates an infinite loop. And where the c might stick at value 2, the check values does walk up through the iterations.

As for the amount of variables involved, I've checked time and again with the console, and all of them are defined, and the values I expected. The Code is located at http://age-of-wonders-3.wikia.com/wiki/MediaWiki:Units.js, but if any parts are requested I'll of course post them here.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible that some other code that is not shown is changing `c`? A bare **c** in `for (c = 0; ... )` is global. You may want to try `for (var c = 0; ...)` and maybe also rename `c` to something with more meaning.

Comment: Both *i* and *c* are being created as global variables when their respective loops start. Reduce the code to the minimum (remove all the debug stuff) and there is no infinite loop.

Comment: BTW, the linked code seems extremely inefficient, e.g. `$(unitabilities[i].getElementsByClassName("vigorousmount")[0]).hasClass("hidden") ===false`. Also, all of your loop counters in all of your functions are global. Seriously bad idea.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out it was the global declaration that screwed me up. It wasn't really intentional, and I think my past c++ experience is to blame here - variables like that are still local there, unless modified in the same look. To be honest, I feel kind of stupid now, but thanks everyone! EDIT: Stephen P, if you post it as a official answer rather than a comment, I'll mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **for of** or **.forEach** on an array